# AWS OpenSearch python client raises a 403 on client.indices.exists() - what permissions are required?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am trying to test whether a particular OpenSearch Index exists via opensearch-py.

I am receiving a 403 error and can't for the life of me establish the correct permissions:

```
2022-07-04 14:11:11,535 - WARNING | L258 log_request_fail (): HEAD https://<blah>.<region>.es.amazonaws.com:443/test-index [status:403 request:0.072s]
```

The call is

```py
if opensearch_client.indices.exists(index='test-index'):
    ...
```

What permissions on the OpenSearch side are required to perform this operation?

I can't see anything relating to the HTTP HEAD operation, for example.

Other operations are working just fine.

Help!

Comment: Did you ever work out which permission `exists` uses?

Comment: @Joe I'm afraid not :( I suppose you could rely on the 403, ugly as it is...

Answer (score 0):

On OpenSearch 2.5 it worked for me with the permission `indices:admin/get`

Hope this helps!